# When I try painting a texture with the fill brush i get a weird result

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying something supposedly very simple which is to fill a texture with a color and I seem to get a weird result:

[image: screenshot]

What am I missing here?

Comment: The picture you posted is really too small, can't even read it. Please post a normal size picture, and insert it correctly in your post with the picture insertion tool, or using the following code: `![description](link)`

Comment: @L0Lock wow, you're right, just saw how blurry it was. updated.

Answer (score 1):

Umm not sure if this is a bug of blender. Because I had the same issue too,  so a workaround is using the uv image editor and painting your texture on the image editor directly, avoid painting throught the 3d viewport blender doesnt like it, dont know why. :)

To enable painting on the image editor only change the tab that says view to paint.

Goodluck
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i need to paint on the 3d viewport :\